# Textbox: keep (simple) formatting from text file

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding, textbox

I read a text file from the hard drive, then I want to put this text in a textbox and keep the same formatting from the file (the tabulations for example).

When I open the file in a simple notepad, the formatting is good, but when putting the text in the textbox, the formatting is kind of weird, i.e:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE
SET ID                         = :id, 
    THENAME                       = :name,
    INFO                       = :info,  
    FILESIZE                       = :size,
    COMPLETEPATH                       = :path
```

Instead of:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE
SET ID                         = :id, 
    THENAME                    = :name,
    INFOS                      = :info,  
    FILESIZE                   = :size,
    COMPLETEPATH               = :path
```

How can I keep the formatting? I tried with the methods of StreamReader and File (ReadToEnd, ReadLine, ReadAllText) with all encoding available (UTF7, UTF8, UTF32, ASCII, UNICODE, BigEndianUnicode).

Comment: It is reading the file so I doubt encoding is the problem.  What is interesting is the first indent is correct.    Examine the space characters between the two column.  I suspect tabs are used but not treated the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is simply the Font - Have you set the font of the textbox to a [monospace font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) (e.g. `Courier`)?

If you set it to e.g. `Times New Roman` or `Calibri` not all letters have the same width resulting in what you described...

Comment: Right, thanks that solved the problem, I will accept your answer within some minutes